# Dictionary with lists: Fastest way to get the key corresponding to the minimum value of the fourth list item?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I'm coding an app where speed is important. Because of this, I want to avoid a loop and use `min` if possible.

Say I have a dictionary containing lists:

```
test = {'test': ['test', 444, 2, 51, 1, 1],
        '222': ['222', 2222, 2, 9, 3, 4],
        '333': ['333', 2222, 6, 6, 5, 9]}
```

What's the fastest way to get the corresponding key of the list item in the [3] spot (fourth element) with the minimum value in the dictionary?

Comment: but `min(list)` uses a loop too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that using `min` won't necessarily be faster than using a for loop, and actually will probably be slower.

[This article](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str) by Guido has a similar optimization problem. The takeaway is that functions like `min` and `map` get to use loops in C rather than Python loops, but they have to do more function lookups. It turns out that Python's loop overhead is less than Python's function lookup overhead, so the loop versions will often be faster. In Guido's words:

> Try to use map(), filter() or reduce() to replace an explicit for loop, but only if you can use a built-in function: map with a built-in function beats for loop, but a for loop with in-line code beats map with a lambda function!

Some timings:

```
test = {'test': ['test', 444, 2, 51, 1, 1],
        '222': ['222', 2222, 2, 9, 3, 4],
        '333': ['333', 2222, 6, 6, 5, 9]}

def using_for_loop():
    curr_min = 999
    for key, lst in test.items():
        val = lst[3]
        if val < curr_min:
            curr_key = key
            curr_min = val
    return curr_key

def using_min():  # From BrenBarn's answer
    return min(test, key=lambda k: test[k][3])

%timeit using_for_loop()
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 724 ns per loop

%timeit using_min()
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.35 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip Roger Fan.  That was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

```
min(test, key=lambda k: test[k][3])
```